# My app working fine in nougat but when i try to run in lollipop and marshmallow

Tags: android, service

Here My Problem is my application is working fine in nougat version. but when i am trying to run in lollipop and marshmallow it not opening the new activity here is my adapter code.

```
 btupdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(mCtx, Main3Activity.class);

//                i.putExtra("Link",btupdate.getText().toString().trim());
//                (or)
                i.putExtra("Link", hero.getLink());
                i.putExtra("username", hero.getUsername());
                i.putExtra("password", hero.getPassword());
                mCtx.startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        btview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(mCtx, Main3Activity.class);
                i.putExtra("Link", hero.getLink());
                i.putExtra("username", hero.getUsername());
                i.putExtra("password", hero.getPassword());
                mCtx.startActivity(i);

            }
```

and here is my Main3Acivity class code.

```
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    message = bundle.getString("Link");
    username = bundle.getString("username");
    password = bundle.getString("password");
```

And i am getting following log.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.lenovo.trainapp, PID: 5018
                  android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
                      at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:672)
                      at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:659)
                      at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:331)
                      at com.example.lenovo.trainapp.ListViewAdapter$1.onClick(ListViewAdapter.java:61)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Help me please.

Comment: `mCtx` should be the `Activity`, not `getApplicationContext()`, which it seems like it is.

Answer (score 0):

Add this and try

i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

Comment: Don't do this, unless you explicitly want to start a new task, in which case, you would've likely already set the flag, knowing exactly what it means.

Comment: Thanks for this help its working fine